# using Geodjango with oracle database

Tags: django, oracle, geodjango

When working with `GeoDjango` I have a problem: when I make migrations then migrate new models the log said "no migrations to apply" and the oracle database still have no new table.

my settings.py is

```
DATABASES = {

    "default": {

        "ENGINE": "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.oracle", 
        "NAME":,
        "USER":,
        "PASSWORD":,
    }   
}
```

I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are learning, see:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.oracle',
    'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
  }
```

}

First you need to create a user and password in your database, Oracle and set up this information in setting.py

You can see more information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/).